# Is it possible to have this kind of role-based authorization?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roles, asp.net-authorization

I'm setting up a role-based authorization in my ASP.NET MVC Web application and I need help with role authorization attributes at different levels.

I've read about it from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and saw that it is possible to have limits like in this example code:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, User")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SetAction1()
    {
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult SetAction2()
    {
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have this kind of role authorization?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class ControlPanelController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SetAction1()
    {
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, User")]
    public ActionResult SetAction2()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: well, what happened when you tried to use it? That would be the best way to find out...

Answer (score 0):

Nope;

When you set `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` on controller, then Only 
an `Administrator` can pass the authorization and `User` role will be prevented. So, User will never reach to that level. But if one user have both `Administrator` and `User` role at the same time then S/he will pass it.

Comment: In short, I should use multiple roles on controller, and single roles on individual actions?

Comment: It's better to do so. But in some specific situations you may want to set Roles as you've shown in your question.